# How to Crop Image And Overwrite Exiting

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file, crop

```
protected void btnCropIt_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("../upload/" + u.Avatar));
    var m = cropImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50));
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("../upload/" + u.Avatar));
    m.Save(Server.MapPath("../upload/" + u.Avatar));
}


private static System.Drawing.Image cropImage(System.Drawing.Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
    Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
    Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
    return (System.Drawing.Image)(bmpCrop);
}

System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("../upload/" + u.Avatar));
```

This line of code throws exception that it can't delete image, it's used by another process. Any Idea? How to overwrite it?

Comment: try to make Image.Clone before passing image to cropImage function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is still using it.  `FromFile()` keeps it locked until the image is disposed.  It's kind of an obscure semantic, but the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) does mention it.

You might try `img.Finalize()` right after `cropImage()` as a simple fix.  If that doesn't work, pull it in with a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), use the [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) Stream constructor overload, then close the FileStream immediately.